# Oracle XML-Hierarchy with child nodes (NEWCONTEXTFROMHIERARCHY)

Tags: xml, oracle, hierarchy

My goal is a `XML` document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IMPORT>
  <PGR name="Product Group 1">
    <PGR name="Product Group 1-1">
      <PGR name="Product Group 1-1-1">
        <PRO name="Product X">
          <PRV name="Product Variant X-1" />
        </PRO>
      </PGR>
    </PGR>
  </PGR>
</IMPORT>
```

My tables with example data:

```
create table PRODUCTS
(
  id             NUMBER(8) not null,
  name           VARCHAR2(100),
  baseproduct    VARCHAR2(100),
  productgroupid NUMBER(8)
);

insert into PRODUCTS (ID, NAME, BASEPRODUCT, PRODUCTGROUPID)
values (1, 'Product Variant 1', 'Product X', 3);

create table PRODUCTGROUPS
(
  id       NUMBER(8) not null,
  parentid NUMBER(8),
  name     VARCHAR2(100)
);

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (1, null, 'Product Group 1');

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (2, 1, 'Product Group 1-1');

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (3, 2, 'Product Group 1-1-1');

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (4, null, 'Product Group 2');

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (5, 4, 'Product Group 2-1');

insert into PRODUCTGROUPS (ID, PARENTID, NAME)
values (6, 5, 'Product Group 2-1-1');
```

Every `PRODUCT` (PRV-Node) has a `BASEPRODUCT` (PRO-Node) and a `PRODUCTGROUP` (PGR-Node). The `PRODUCTGROUPS` are hierarchical.

What I get so far is the `XML` for the `PRODUCTGROUP-Hierarchy` with:

```
select DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE(DBMS_XMLGEN.NEWCONTEXTFROMHIERARCHY('
select level, xmlelement("PGR", XMLATTRIBUTES(NAME)) 
from PRODUCTGROUPS
start with PARENTID is null
connect by nocycle PARENTID = PRIOR ID')) from dual
```

I also have the desired XML-Structure, but without the PRODUCTGROUP-Hierarchy:

```
select P.ID,
  XMLROOT(
    XMLELEMENT("IMPORT",  
      XMLELEMENT("PGR", XMLATTRIBUTES(G.NAME as "name"),
        XMLELEMENT("PRO", XMLATTRIBUTES(P.BASEPRODUCT as "name"),
          XMLELEMENT("PRV", XMLATTRIBUTES(P.NAME as "name"))
        )   
      )        
    ) 
, version '1.0" encoding="utf-8') as XML
from PRODUCTS P join PRODUCTGROUPS G on P.PRODUCTGROUPID = G.ID
```

Now I do not know, how to combine these two approaches to get the desired `XML-Structure` with the `PRODUCTGROUP-Hierarchy`. Is there a way to get this with `Oracle-XML-Functions`?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I never seen this function (`NEWCONTEXTFROMHIERARCHY`), but this is something I managed to do. I made a function which creates needed part of hierarchical tree and unions two additional parameters (base product and product). Then I used `newcontextfromhierarchy`. This way function returns whole node.

```
create or replace function xml_hier(i_id in varchar2, i_base in varchar2, i_name in varchar2) return xmltype is
  v_ret xmltype;
begin
  select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(dbms_xmlgen.newcontextfromhierarchy('
    with t as (
      select level lvl, xmlelement("PGR", XMLATTRIBUTES(NAME))
        from PRODUCTGROUPS
        where id in (select id 
                       from PRODUCTGROUPS
                       connect by prior PARENTID = ID start with id = '||i_id||')
        connect by PARENTID = prior ID
        start with parentid is null)
    select * from t 
    union all
    select (select max(lvl) + 1 from t), XMLELEMENT("PRO", XMLATTRIBUTES('''||i_base||''' as "name")) from dual
    union all
    select (select max(lvl) + 2 from t), XMLELEMENT("PRV", XMLATTRIBUTES('''||i_name||''' as "name")) from dual'))
  into v_ret
  from dual;
  return v_ret;
end;
```

So, with your tables created, I run:

```
select p.id,
       xmlroot(
         xmlelement("IMPORT",  
           xml_hier(g.id, p.baseproduct, p.name))
         , version '1.0" encoding="utf-8') as xml
  from products p 
  join productgroups g on p.productgroupid = g.id;
```

and the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IMPORT>
  <PGR NAME="Product Group 1">
    <PGR NAME="Product Group 1-1">
      <PGR NAME="Product Group 1-1-1">
        <PRO name="Product X">
          <PRV name="Product Variant 1"/>
        </PRO>
      </PGR>
    </PGR>
  </PGR>
</IMPORT>
```

Hierarchical query at first works in reversed direction, in order to find ancestors. Then it's going normally, using only already known `id`'s.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to perfectly fits my needs!